# Parameter that will only show the actual max days of month

Tags: parameters, tableau-desktop

I am creating a table in Tableau to show month to date spend that can be filtered at the Month/Year level (this is one filter with month and year combined) but can also be filtered by the day of the month to show the data up to that day.  The user can only select one Month/Year and one Day at a time. The underlying data is at the day level, and the table looks like this:

[image]

What I want is to have the day parameter show only those vales that are actually relevant to the month selected. So if October is selected it shows 1-31, but if November is selected it will only show 1-30. Currently the parameter is pulling data from a field that calculates just the numeric day portion of the date. I tried using a filter for this, but then it would only include the numeric day selected, and I need to show the data for all the days of that month up to the numeric day selected.

I've searched what feels like everywhere and can't find an answer for this- any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The range limits for a parameter are either static or can be loaded from a database table when the workbook opens - neither of which is adjustable for your purpose.

If this is important enough to you, you could put a bit more effort - to embed your visualization inside a web page. Then you could implement your "parameter" control user interface with HTML, CSS and JavaScript to behave however you like, and then use the [**Tableau embedding API**](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/embedding_api/en-us/index.html) to set the Tableau parameter to match.

To quickly get an idea of the API's capability, check out the [**Tableau embedding API tutorial**](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/embedding_api/en-us/tutorial/tutorial.htm) It's a very well-done tutorial -- clearly showing the main concepts in just about 5 minutes, or letting you drill down for more detail if you like.

Once you are already embedding a viz, using an HTML control is pretty straightforward, but it takes extra effort to set it up. You can get some nice effects this way, but if your only reason to do so is to avoid showing some irrelevant date options, I would choose to invest my time on something more impactful. To me, being able to select Feb 31 as a date limit would be annoying, but not really critical. YMMV.

Another option to extend Tableau is to either write or buy a Tableau dashboard extension. See the [Tableau exchange](https://extensiongallery.tableau.com) or [Extensions API](https://tableau.github.io/extensions-api/)

One last very simple option is to make a single parameter with a date datatype, instead of having separate string and integer parameters for month and day. That way the user can select a date from a calendar type parameter control, and Tableau will ensure the date is valid.